# How can I call facebook SDK in http?

Tags: javascript

I'm use https and http in parallel.
So I would like to use the javascript sdk to use the user login status(FB.LoginStatus), but when I call sdk from a page that does not use http, I get a cross browsing error.

If I try to use iframe, I get the same error.
Is there a way to get the login status using a javascript sdk on a non-https page?

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can not (or at least you should not). More and more browsers are blocking mixed calls. If you start a https request, then further http requests inside the main page will trigger at least a warning to the user. Then some APIs are no longer working on http (for example, the location API used to work on http pages, but it does not work anymore).

Even if you can implement a workaround, you app/site will not be futureproof.

Try to implement https all over your site/app, since there are web-sites that can provide you with free certificates (https://letsencrypt.org/).